# is There a way to create a apk file from App that created by unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm planning to make an app with Unity that will allow you to create a game without write a code, and now I want to know is there a way to create an apk file through a tool we call in c# to allow users to convert their game to apk?

Comment: So you are planning in making a game engine with a game engine?

Comment: @JoaoSoares Look its like a game engine that allow you to create a game without coding

Comment: Afaik Unity strictly forbids such a use case (or in general to use Unity to create an app that allows you to create other apps). I'm not sure anymore if this applies to such use cases in general (the case I know was content creation by replicating the SceneView, Hierarchy, Inspector and runtime written components on runtime) .. you should read the [Terms](https://unity3d.com/legal/terms-of-service) and in particular [Additional Software Terms](https://unity3d.com/de/legal/terms-of-service/software) very carefully in that regard

Comment: In particular the compilation of the projects to different target platforms is one of Unity's core features -> pretty sure you are not allowed to replicate this even if it would be possible .. and if it is possible at all it is very very far from trivial and this question as far from on-topic here ;) Also why should your users use your app? What advantage does it bring against just simply use Unity and [Visual Scripting](https://unity.com/products/unity-visual-scripting)?